# w3school layout bootstrap not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded a bootstrap from the net which is a layout from w3schools. I tried to run it from my server and it worked but the css or design isn't. it is just plain html. Do you guys have any idea whats wrong? :(

Comment: Could you post a link to the page on your server and link to the layout on the w3schools website?

Comment: localhost/voyage-pack/web/index.html http://p.w3layouts.com/demos/voyage/web/index.html# @GrzegorzAdamKowalski

Comment: OK, what do you mean it's just plain HTML? Does that mean that you see HTML code or that you see text content only without styling? Could you provide screenshot?

Comment: pure html, doesnt run the css part

Comment: What do you mean by pure html? Do you see not interpreted HTML code or do you see interpreted HTML (text content) without styling? If you see not interepreted HTML code, then your web server is incorrectly configured. If you see interpreted HTML but without styling, then you should check in browser console for any error messages, check if all template files are accessible etc.